# Duplicate elements in a JSON result - Asp.Net Core API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, automapper

Again, I have a question about this tree structure. The point is that after calling the endpoint, which retrieves the entire tree, some data is duplicated. It will be best when I show JSON.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Node1",
        "subNodes": [
            {
                "name": "Node1_SubNode1",
                "subNodes": [],
                "subLeaves": [
                    {
                        "name": "File1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Node1_SubNode2",
                "subNodes": [],
                "subLeaves": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Node1_SubNode3",
                "subNodes": [],
                "subLeaves": []
            }
        ],
        "subLeaves": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Node1_SubNode1",
        "subNodes": [],
        "subLeaves": [
            {
                "name": "File1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Node1_SubNode2",
        "subNodes": [],
        "subLeaves": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Node1_SubNode3",
        "subNodes": [],
        "subLeaves": []
    }
]
```

at the end you can see that the nodes have repeated because they have already appeared in subnodes above.

I get nodes in the standard way:

```
var nodes = await _context.Nodes.Include(x => x.SubLeaves).ToListAsync();
```

My Node entity:

```
    public class Node
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int NodeId { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ParentNodeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ParentNodeId")]
        public Node ParentNode { get; set; }
        public List<Node> SubNodes { get; set; }
        public List<Leaf> SubLeaves { get; set; }
        public Node()
        {
            SubNodes = new List<Node>();
            SubLeaves = new List<Leaf>();
        }
    }
```

And model builder configuration:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
                .HasMany(cat => cat.SubNodes)
                .WithOne(cat => cat.ParentNode);
```

is there a way to solve it quickly? Maybe Can I do this using automapper.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `where` clause to your data context query to only return nodes that have no parent nodes.

I don't know the data structure of your Node class so I can't give the specific code to use.

Comment: but when I do this I also do not receive subnodes. I updated my post

Comment: You should enable proxies and lazy loading in EF, that'll ensure you get the subnodes.

Comment: @KrystianWolański Just do the filtering in memory AFTER executing the database query and materializing the result. e.g. `var rootNodes = nodes.Where(n => n.ParentNode == null);`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data